# Como detectar se um artigo do Wordpress foi carregado em uma lightbox?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, plugin

Eu estou criando um site de notícias, estou usando o Wordpress como CMS e estou usando um plugin JQuery (Magnific Popup) para abrir os artigos em uma *lightbox*.

Fiz o `single.php` sem o cabeçalho e sem o rodapé, já que não vai precisar, pois a *lightbox* abre em cima da *home* do meu site. Então eu queria que quando o usuário clicasse no "Artigo" na *home* do site, ele abrisse em uma *lightbox*, e quando ele acessasse o "Artigo" pelo link direto, mostrasse o artigo como uma página normal, com cabeçalho e rodapé.

Comment: A questão é: como está funcionando esse seu ligtbox? Podes postar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de usar o single, crie um arquivo somente para o Lightbox.

Deixe o single padrão e o outro arquivo sem cabeçalho e sem o rodapé.

Comment: Obrigada, fiz meio que parecido com o que você disse, mais ao invés de usar outro arquivo, passei um parâmetro pela url, assim quando o usuário clica no artigo na Home do site, o parâmetro 't' é passado, então o single.php detecta que esse parâmetro foi passado e tira o cabeçalho e o rodapé, e quando os usuários chegam ao artigo pelo link que eu mandei a eles(sem o parâmetro 't'), o single.php coloca o Cabeçalho e o Rodapé. Obrigado pela sua ajuda

Comment: ótima ideia muito bom da um up se a resposta ajudou.